# how can I use two Webviews in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webview, viewcontroller

i am a beginner in swift development and i need help.
so how can i put two UIWebView in same view controller?

my code works fine.
but I would like to add one more under my current UIWebView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))


       } 
}
```

I tried this but it gives me a error.
anyone a solution?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))


    }


@IBOutlet weak var webView2: UIWebView!

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    webView2.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))

}
```

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing just that?

Comment: i would like to create a webview with a another link

Comment: Then go ahead and do that, add another outlet `otherWebView`, connect it to a second `UIWebView` and then let that second view load another url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare another one ! I am assuming you are doing this through the interface builder.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var webView2: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    let url2 = URL(string: "url here")
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    webview2.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))


   } 
}
```